# Identify UIImageView and UITextView created in loop iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextview

I'm working in Xcode and i have a loop cycle in which i dynamically create UIImageViews and UITextviews and insert them in a UIScrollView. In every row, i create 4 UIImageViews and 2 UITextViews, so the code looks like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<dim; i++){

    UITextView *textView1= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth/2, 37)];
    UITextView *textView2= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth/2, 0, screenWidth/2, 37)];

     UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50,screenWidth/4,100)];
     UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth/4,50,screenWidth/4,100)];
     UIImageView *imageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth/2,50,screenWidth/4,100)];
     UIImageView *imageView4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth*3/4,50,screenWidth/4,100)];
}
```

The code to set images in UIImageViews, text in UITextViews and show them in the UIScrollView works great and i don't post it because it's too long.

My problem is: when i click on an image, i call methods in which i want to make change to the ImageViews and TextViews of the same row, how can i identify them?

Detecting the image clicked is not a problem using the recognizer.view, to detect other images of the same row i tried to set a tag to the views and then call "viewWithTag" to find them, but i have problems because the elements of the same row have the same tag value and i make confusion.

My target is for example:

- When i click on imageView1 in the first row should change image in imageView3 of the same row.
- When i click on imageView3 in the fourth row should change text in textView2 of the same row.
- And so on..

Is there any alternative method without using the tag attribute?

I hope I explained myself

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off using a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView` for what you want to do. As this would allow you to access the cells at a certain row/index and with a custom cell subclass you could access the image properties.

Comment: @Evan inserting a UITextView into a UITableViewCell is asking for a world of pain if you want fine-grained control over the layout. I've done it, and there are definitely times when it should be avoided. It has to be taken on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert fair enough. Another option is to make a `UIView` subclass and expose everything as properties. You can avoid tags if you think through your structure.

Comment: Or you could even have a UIViewController for each "row" in the view. In fact, probably the best solution is to have your own custom class but structure it the same as UITable/CollectionView. There are many ways to slice t his cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tag property, but without using the same tag more then once. Some little math should do the trick to identify views in the same row by their tags...

**BUT**:
I wouldn't recommend using tags. Make yourself a custom view class, e.g.  `MyRow`, containing the 6 views belonging together as subviews. From there you can go anywhere.

Got a  problem, invent an object. Always works.

**BIGGER BUT**: I'd strongly recommend to go with `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`.

Comment: Ok i solved. I've done a view that contains all the other views (for every loop). So in the method called when the user clicks on an image, i can search imageViews and textViews only in the view that i want, identified by the tag. And there is no problem if the imageViews have the same tag, if they're in different "container". It wasn't so difficult, but you helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` has a "tag" property, which you can use for anything you want. The default value is `0` and it doesn't do anything at all, except store the value.

Typically you would set the tag to be an array index.

So you could do:

```
textView1.tag = i;
textView2.tag = i;
imageView1.tag = i;
imageView2.tag = i;
imageView3.tag = i;
imageView4.tag = i;
```

Or perhaps something more clever, like:

```
textView1.tag = 1000000 + i;
textView2.tag = 2000000 + i;
imageView1.tag = 3000000 + i;
imageView2.tag = 4000000 + i;
imageView3.tag = 5000000 + i;
imageView4.tag = 6000000 + i;
```

Or maybe you could have an array property mapping them:

```
@property NSMutableArray tagMap;

textView1.tag = self.tagMap.count;
[self.tagMap addObject:@{@"var": @"textView1", @"index":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]}];
```

Comment: I already thought this solution, but it's more complicated. The images are taken from the web, ten images for every loop, and the scrollview can be updated with other images. So, if i use this method, in every loop i'll have duplicated tags and makes confusion

Comment: Then you need to use an NSMutableArray as a map of the tags to something. Maybe you can store the URL to the image in the array for example.